# Timing Tool for work

Tags: javascript

I have built a tool for timing indirect workers, it consists of a start and stop button which both place a time stamp into the google sheet and then calculates the difference to record a time. It works great however when I share it with some people it does not allow them to use it saying that they do no have access to run the script. If they open script editor they can manually run it however that will no fly because I will be sending this out to approximately 50 people.

Here is the code and start and stop are two different scripts. Please let me know if I am missing something and I appreciate the help. Thanks

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
var start = new Date();

function StartScript() {
    var last = ss.getLastRow();

    ss.getRange(last+1,1).setValue(last+1)

    var source = ss.getRange(last+1,1).getValue();
    source = Number(source);

    if (source <= 16) {    
        ss.getRange(last+1,2).setValue(start);
    }
    else {
        ss.getRange(last+1,2).setValue("Stop Timing");
    }
}

function stop() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var date = new Date();

    var last1 = ss.getLastRow();
    ss.getRange(last1, 3).setValue(date);

    var lastrow = ss.getLastRow()

    ss.getRange("D" + (lastrow)).setFormula("=C" + (lastrow) + "-B" + (lastrow));
}
```